# second ajax call will take long to complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

EDIT: I have checked that my ajax call are set to run async. The code will fire the ajax_counter_upload every 10 seconds but all the request will be in progress till the first one has completed and will report, for all the call, a 100% progress.

I have an ajax call that will take minutes to complete. So I created a second one that will provide user a status update on the first call progress. 
It used to work fine but now I see that the second call will be active longer than the first one and so will provide the feedback only after the first call has already completed. Nothing has changed: no updates, no version change in any software and so on
My code is the following:

```
var intervalID;

function counterUpdater(){
    intervalID = setInterval(ajax_counter_upload,10000);    
}
function ajax_counter_upload(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "plan/counter.php",
        data: {tipo:'BP'},
        success: function(data){
            $("#spinner_msg").fadeTo(200,0.1,
                function(){
                    $(this).html(data);
                    $(this).fadeTo(900,1);
                });
        }
    });
}
function ajax_submit(){
    var submit_val=$("#stato").serialize();
    dest="plan/new_bp1.php";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: dest,
        data: submit_val,
        success: function(data){ 
            data1=data.split("|");
            if(data1[0]=="Successo"){ 
                $("#spnmsg").fadeTo(200,0.1,
                    function(){$(this).removeClass().addClass("spn_success").html(data1[1]).fadeTo(900,1)});
                }else if(data1[0]=="Errore"){
                    $("#spnmsg").fadeTo(200,0.1,
                    function(){$(this).removeClass().addClass("spn_error").html(data1[1]).fadeTo(900,1)});  
                }
        },
        complete: function(){
            clearInterval(intervalID);
            $('#spinner_msg').html('');         
            setTimeout(function(){ $('.container').load('plan/home.php');},2000); 
        }
    });
    $('#spinner_msg').html('Avvio la creazione del nuovo business plan');
    setTimeout(function(){counterUpdater();},2000);
}
```

So every two seconds counterUpdater will do it's magic to provide the feedback to the user. 
NOTE: the counterUpdater call will succeed but only will take too much time to complete

Comment: Actually this is what trigger the second Ajax call every 2 seconds while ajax_submit is running

Comment: It sounds like your server handles only one request at a time. What said your network tab (browser console) regarding first `ajax_counter_upload` request? Pending status?  And are you sure you aren't setting globally ajax request to be sync? You can check it using `$.ajaxPrefilter(function( options) {
    console.log(options.async);
});`

Comment: No, I have not set Ajax call to be sync, I'm sure and I have verified. From one day to the other this code stopped working as expected. The second Ajax (just retrieve one row from a single row table) waits for an answer for more than a minute (looking at the console)

Comment: Is it dedicated server, mutualised or local one?

Comment: It's a dedicated, much oversized (for now) server

Comment: Ok sorry, but if you didn't change any config server side, if you aren't brided in some way, i don't know what can happen. Maybe just your server side script called on first request consumes to much server side resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clearInterval(intervalID);` needs to be put inside `success` of `ajax_counter_upload()` function   and not in `ajax_submit()`

Comment: No OP wants to stop checking for progress once `ajax_submit` request has completed, i guess

Comment: @A.Wolff and Lelio : but `ajax_counter_upload()` will fire again and again after specified interval time since Lelio is using `setInterval`... So it may go in a loop ,,right ? if I am not mistaken...or better use `setTimeout`

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong, but it seems like `ajax_counter_upload` gets its initial call after 12 seconds.

You call `counterUpdater()`; after two seconds and then start `ajax_counter_upload` every 10 seconds.
Try reducing the 10000(ms) of `setInterval` to a lower number.

Comment: Sorry but this is not the issue. The issue is counterUpdater calls will complete after the Ajax_updater has completed

Comment: Too bad, you could try to trigger the timeout before the ajax request, that shouldn't change anything, but it could help...

Comment: So the call is to late, not the the request?

Comment: @LelioFaieta also, did you try a different browser? Maybe your browser updated and thats what broke it?